# BelongsTo in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table which is named **cars** with 2 fields `id, matriculation`. 
Then, I have another table which is named **series** with 2 fields `id, name`.

I have created my `fk_serie` on my table **cars**.

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('cars', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('matriculation', 25);
            $table->integer('fk_serie')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('fk_serie')->references('id_serie')->on('serie');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Here is my information about the table **series**.

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('series', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name', 30);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

In my model, I only have a function on the model **Car**.

```
public function serie(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Serie', 'fk_serie');
}
```

I don't have nothing in my model **Serie**

```
class Serie extends Model
{
    //
}
```

Is it normal that the model **Serie** is empty? 
Because, my join works.

What do you think ?

[image: overview]

Is there an error?

Comment: If you don't need to write query like this: `Serie::with('car')->find($id)` it's normal.

Comment: There's an error here `$table->foreign('fk_serie')->references('id_serie')->on('serie');` . It should be `...->references('id')...`. I'd answer in more detail but I don't understand the question. You could add the method you're calling, what are you expecting, and what are you getting. That should clarify it.

Comment: @ dparoli: thank you dparoli ;-)

Comment: @brnd0: Thank you. I edit the `...->references('id_serie')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `Dparoli` mentioned in comments if you don't need the below query then your above structure of relationship is normal

```
Serie::with('cars')->find($id)
```

But if you want to setup relationship in `Serie` Model you can do something like below:

```
class Serie extends Model
{
   public function cars() { 
       return $this->hasMany('App\Car', 'fk_serie'); // your relationship
   } 
}
```

And after that you can do:

```
$series = Serie::with('cars')->find($id); //eager loading cars
$cars = $series->first()->cars;
```

Comment: Glad to know it helped :)